# Word similarity across a large array

Tags: java, similarity

I have a very large array of strings (32k words or so) and i was wanting to check the similarity of the entire array in an efficient way. I wanted it to be returned in a percent. I also don't know how many spots will be in the array exactly. I don't know what the most efficient way to do this is. My current idea is to check the similarity between every two words in the array, then average that similarity. I was hoping to find a more efficient solution.
This is what I tried so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;   
public class Trial2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Double> averageValues = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<>(); //holds all the words in the list
    for(int i = 0; i < temp.size() - 1; i++) {
        double k = StringUtils.getLevenshteinDistance(temp.get(i), temp.get(i + 1));
        averageValues.add(k/(double)temp.get(i).length())
    }
    double average;
    for(int i = 0; i < averageValues.size(); i++) {
        average += averageValues.get(i);
    }
    average = average/averageValues.size();
}
}
```

Assuming my temp list is already full. The problem with this code is that its already embedded in 2 forloops and I didnt want to hit n^3. Are there any other ways to solve this problem

Please help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Right now, it reads as "write this code for me," which is off-topic for StackOverflow. Also: This isn't a Big Data problem (I edited out that tag). Please edit your question with more specifics, before it ends up being closed.

Comment: im sorry i made it look that way. I just wanted to be pointed in the write direction rather than have someone write the code for me.

Answer (score 0):

For the following lets assume that the length of the individual entries (e.g. words) does not increase.

Your algorithm is only O(n) in the number of entries in the array because it compares every entry only to the next (not to every other entry). The tradeoff is that it (only) delivers a heuristic estimate of the total similarity. Good: your algorithm visits every entry, so each entry has at least some influence on the heuristic result (but see about statistics below).

Suggestions:

To avoid grow-cost, you could give averageValues an initial size equal to that of temp (-1 if you want). But this is not even needed if you do the following.

You could eliminate the second loop by letting the first just accumulate the result:

```
sumOfDifferences += k/(double)temp.get(i).length();
```

Then after the loop:

```
average = sumOfDifferences/temp.size();
```

This might run faster because in your version there is a chance, that the entries are nolonger in cache when the second loop runs, if another thread/process was running at that time.
This also lets you remove the averageValues ArrayList so there is nolonger the grow-cost.

Not an optimization but just to consider: think about whether dividing by `(double)temp.get(i).length()` makes sense for the thing you are trying to achieve.

Statistically, it might by troublesome that you are always comparing to the next entry. E.g. there would be a huge bias if the words are sorted. Think about whether it would be better to first randomize the array.